# iOS - get objects from RESTful service with RestKit

Tags: ios, rest, ios7, restkit, restkit-0.20

I am trying to get data from my RESTful services. I get this code from some tutorials and I hope I get it right. I think I am just missing something. I get this:

```
RKObjectManager *manager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www....com"]];

NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
manager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;


NSDictionary *parentObjectMapping = @{
                                      @"lat" : @"latitude",
                                      @"long" : @"longitude",
                                      };

RKEntityMapping *cityMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([City class]) inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[cityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
                                                       @"name" : @"name",
                                                       @"country" : @"country",
                                                       @"population" : @"population",
                                                       }];

[cityMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:parentObjectMapping];

[manager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[[RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:cityMapping
                                                                                   pathPattern:nil
                                                                                       keyPath:@"results"
                                                                                   statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)]
                                           ]];
[manager getObjectsAtPath:@"/api/autocomplete?q=bos"
               parameters:nil
                  success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult)
{
}
                  failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
}];
```

Last few lines I added because I think I was missing something like execute. Now when I run this I get error:

```
Unable to perform mapping: No `managedObjectContext` assigned.
```

How can I fix this? Did I make other things allright? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error already suggests: you are missing the `managedObjectContext`. Add it using `[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];` (the line after creating the store itself)

Comment: Then I get `Cannot create managed object contexts: The persistent store coordinator does not have any persistent stores. This likely means that you forgot to add a persistent store or your attempt to do so failed with an error.` but I don't want to save it to any persistent object. What if I just want to show it to user and then forget it?

Comment: If you don't want to save it, why are you using RKEntityMappings? From the docs: `RKEntityMapping objects model an object mapping with a Core Data destination entity`

Comment: Take a look at this example, it might help: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/development/Examples/RKTwitter/Classes/RKTwitterAppDelegate.m

Comment: Then I guess I must change a few lines and that Twitter example looks like everything I need. Thanks for help.